# Extension like Resharper for extracting interfaces in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: interface, extract

Does anyone know of a solid refactoring tool that will allow you to quickly extract interfaces from classes with the option to place it on the clipboard or replace a file etc--the same way Resharper does. It would be nice if it was free but I would be willing to pay a small fee since I spend a lot of time updating interfaces.  Resharper is far too heavy/buggy and expensive.

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: VS 2017 has that option built in - mark the class, press `ctrl` and `.`, and you'll see `extract interface`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know. It just results in more keystrokes and mouse clicks since it does not put the extracted interface on the clipboard or replace the current interface. It's great for the first extraction but after that it gets in the way.

Comment: @DangNguyen That ship sailed long ago. The policy, if it is even enforced anymore, is way out of date.